# grid_map not working properly on Melodic - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ros-melodic, octomap, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am following the [tutorial](https://github.com/ANYbotics/grid_map/blob/master/grid_map_demos/src/simple_demo_node.cpp) on how to create and launch a `grid_map`. Because I am not familiar with this tool offered by `ROS` I had to follow it precisely. However, despite that there is an error that is keeping the compiler to build the project.
I was afraid that some of the function were deprecated from a previous pull request `#67` as explained [here](https://github.com/ANYbotics/grid_map/pull/73/commits/09890cee5cdea797fa0fccb4e79117eb6603dbc9) but I am not totally sure it could be related.
The tutorial I am following is the first one called `grid_map/grid_map_demos/src/simple_demo_node.cpp` of the link I provided. The errors I am obtaining are highlighted as `<-- Error Here` in my code.

Below the snipped of code I amusing:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <grid_map_ros/grid_map_ros.hpp>
#include <grid_map_msgs/GridMap.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace grid_map;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        // initialize node and publisher
    ros::init(argc, argv, "grid_map_test");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<grid_map::GridMap>("grid_map", 1, true);

    // create grid map
    GridMap map({"elevation"});
    map.setFrameId("map");
    map.setGeometry(Length(1.2, 2.0), 0.03);
    ROS_INFO("Created map with size %f x %f m (%i x %i cells).",
             map.getLength().x(), map.getLength().y(), // <-- Error Here
             map.getSize()(0), map.getSize()(1)); // <-- Error Here

    // work with grid-map in a loop
    ros::Rate rate(30.0);
    while (nh.ok()) {
        // add data to grid-map.
        ros::Time time = ros::Time::now();
        for(GridMapIterator it(map); !it.isPastEnd(); ++it) // <-- Error Here
        {
            Position position;
            map.getPosition(*it, position);
            map.at("elevation", *it) = -0.04 + 0.2 * std::sin(3.0 * time.toSec() + 5.0 * position.y()) * position.x(); // <-- Error Here
        }

        // publish a grid map
        map.setTimestamp(time.toNSec());
        grid_map_msgs::GridMap msg;
        GridMapRosConverter::toMessage(map, msg);
        pub.publish(msg);
        ROS_INFO_THROTTLE(1.0, "Grid map (timestamp %f) published.", msg.info.header.stamp.toSec());

        // wait for next cycle
        rate.sleep();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**What I tried so far:**

**1)** I found [this](https://github.com/ANYbotics/grid_map/issues/67) which seems to be resolved in [here](https://github.com/ANYbotics/grid_map/pull/73/commits/09890cee5cdea797fa0fccb4e79117eb6603dbc9). It seems that my problem could be (but I am not sure) due to `CMake` and I am including the `CMakeLists.txt` file below for completeness.
Also if I include `Eigen3` or if I do not include `Eigen3` it does not change the result unfortunately. The code below is the one I am currently using:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(map_ros)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)
find_package(octomap REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    roscpp
    sensor_msgs
    std_msgs
    message_generation
    pcl_ros
    pcl_conversions
    geometry_msgs
    nav_msgs
    grid_map_core
    grid_map_ros
    grid_map_cv
    grid_map_filters
    grid_map_loader
    grid_map_msgs
    grid_map_octomap
    grid_map_rviz_plugin
    grid_map_visualization
    cv_bridge
    octomap_msgs
    filters
    eigen3
    )

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  DEPENDS
      roscpp
      sensor_msgs
      std_msgs
      message_generation
      pcl_ros
      pcl_conversions
      geometry_msgs
      nav_msgs
      grid_map_core
      grid_map_ros
      grid_map_cv
      grid_map_filters
      grid_map_loader
      grid_map_msgs
      grid_map_octomap
      grid_map_rviz_plugin
      grid_map_visualization
      cv_bridge
      octomap_msgs
      filters
      eigen3
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${roscpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${std_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${OCTOMAP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
link_libraries(${OCTOMAP_LIBRARIES})

link_directories(${OCTOMAP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${roscpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(map_test src/map_test.cpp ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(map_test
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    ${OCTOMAP_LIBRARIES})
```

**2)** Adding the following line as advised by the [pull out request](https://github.com/ANYbotics/grid_map/pull/73/commits/09890cee5cdea797fa0fccb4e79117eb6603dbc9) didn't work:

```
CATKIN_DEPENDS
  DEPENDS
    #Eigen3
  CFG_EXTRAS ${PROJECT_NAME}-extras.cmake
```

**3)** I am not sure if this is a solution but I added from [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249140/find-package-eigen3-for-cmake) the following code at the beginning of the `CMake` file:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

**4)** Always from the same [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249140/find-package-eigen3-for-cmake) I added the following lines [because point **3)** didnt work] at the the `CMake`:

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
SET( EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR "$ENV{EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}" )
IF( NOT EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR )
    MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "Please point the environment variable EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR to the include directory of your Eigen3 installation.")
ENDIF()
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ( "${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}" )
```

And with my surprise those lines lead to the following warning:
`CMake Error at map_ros/CMakeLists.txt:12 (MESSAGE): Please point the environment variable EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR to the include directory of your Eigen3 installation.`

And the strange fact is that `Eigen3` is installed on my  laptop.

In case you would like to see the out of my laptop see:

[image: error]

The following messages were received:
`no member named 'y' in 'Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>'`
`no member named 'x' in 'Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>'`

`no member named 'y' in 'Eigen::Array<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>'`
`no member named 'x' in 'Eigen::Array<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>'`

But I don't know if this could be relevant to my problem.

**Compiler Errors:**

**Error 1**
`/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/message_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value() [with M = grid_map::GridMap]’: /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/message_traits.h:228:102:   required from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::md5sum() [with M = grid_map::GridMap]’ /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/advertise_options.h:92:39:   required from ‘void ros::AdvertiseOptions::init(const string&, uint32_t, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const SubscriberStatusCallback&) [with M = grid_map::GridMap; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; uint32_t = unsigned int; ros::SubscriberStatusCallback = boost::function<void(const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher&)>]’ /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:252:7:   required from ‘ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const string&, uint32_t, bool) [with M = grid_map::GridMap; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; uint32_t = unsigned int]’ /home/emanuele/catkin_ws/src/map_ros/src/map_test.cpp:15:77:   required from here /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/message_traits.h:121:28: error: ‘__s_getMD5Sum’ is not a member of ‘grid_map::GridMap’ return M::__s_getMD5Sum().c_str();`

**Error 2**
`/home/emanuele/catkin_ws/src/map_ros/src/map_test.cpp:15:77:   required from here /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/message_traits.h:138:30: error: ‘__s_getDataType’ is not a member of ‘grid_map::GridMap’ return M::__s_getDataType().c_str();`

**Error 3**
`/home/emanuele/catkin_ws/src/map_ros/src/map_test.cpp:15:77:   required from here /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/message_traits.h:155:39: error: ‘__s_getMessageDefinition’ is not a member of ‘grid_map::GridMap’ return M::__s_getMessageDefinition().c_str();`

**CONCLUSION:**
I am left with this possibilities and I am not sure on what the problem could be:

1. Possible `CMake` error?
2. Pull Request not working properly/or deprecated?
3. Eigen3 error?

I have tried all I was able to think about and I am short in ideas now. If anyone notice something or can point to the right direction to solve this problem it would be great.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324591/grid_map-not-working-properly-on-melodic---ubuntu-18.04/) by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2019-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:
Not an answer but some observations:

- remove the `link_directories(..)`: they should not be needed (if they are, something else is broken)
- apart from `eigen3`, all the pkgs that you list under `DEPENDS` in your `catkin_package(..)` call should be listed as `CATKIN_DEPENDS`
- the `eigen3` under `DEPENDS` should be listed as `EIGEN3` (note the full caps).
- you already have `pcl_ros` and `pcl_conversions` listed as `COMPONENTS` in `find_package(catkin ..)`, so don't do a `find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)` separately. There is no need.
- all the pkgs that you `find_package(catkin ..)` do not need individual `include_directories(..)` or `find_package(..)` statements. Remove them. `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `catkin_LIBRARIES` will be the union of all of them, so it takes care of them.
- remove the `CFG_EXTRAS` if you still have it: it's not needed in your pkg

finally: please don't pose screenshots of code. It's all text. Just copy-paste it into your question.

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2019-06-04**:
Thanks gvdhoorn for taking the time to read my question. It was indeed a `CMake` problem and all the observations you listed did solve the problem. My `CMake` is not complaining anymore and the program is compiling :). I will post the updated `CMake` response for other users in case needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the observations of gvdhoorn, I am adding below the `CMake` file that was causing the non-compilation problem. All the listed observations needs to be followed and applied and below I am providing the correct template for your `CMake` project in case you need for the future:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(map_ros)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
find_package(octomap REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    roscpp
    sensor_msgs
    std_msgs
    message_generation
    pcl_ros
    pcl_conversions
    geometry_msgs
    nav_msgs
    grid_map_core
    grid_map_ros
    grid_map_cv
    grid_map_filters
    grid_map_loader
    grid_map_msgs
    grid_map_octomap
    grid_map_rviz_plugin
    grid_map_visualization
    cv_bridge
    octomap_msgs
    filters
    )

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
      roscpp
      sensor_msgs
      std_msgs
      message_generation
      pcl_ros
      pcl_conversions
      geometry_msgs
      nav_msgs
      grid_map_core
      grid_map_ros
      grid_map_cv
      grid_map_filters
      grid_map_loader
      grid_map_msgs
      grid_map_octomap
      grid_map_rviz_plugin
      grid_map_visualization
      cv_bridge
      octomap_msgs
      filters
      DEPENDS EIGEN3
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(map_test src/map_test.cpp ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(map_test ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) with karma: 108 on 2019-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:
you have this:

> ```
> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS [..] Eigen3)
> ```

`Eigen3` is not a catkin package, so you cannot use `find_package(catkin ..)` to find it. You have to use `find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)` instead.

Also: why do you still have things like:

```
include_directories(${roscpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${std_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${OCTOMAP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

those are not needed, as they are included in `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS`.

`octomap` is also a ROS package, so no need to `find_package(..)` it separately.

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2019-06-04**:
Thanks for noticing ad sorry for the error but I have been working on this all night. I update the answer :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:
You now still have a separate `link_libraries(${OCTOMAP_LIBRARIES})` which should not be necessary either. And you also have it in the `target_link_libraries(..)` which is not needed.

And if we're being strict: you should add a `DEPENDS EIGEN3` to your `catkin_package(..)` call.

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2019-06-04**:
Thanks for catching the other parts! I updated the `CMake` file with all the comments.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:
But now you added `Eigen3` to `find_package(catkin ..)`: why? It is not a Catkin package.

Other comments:

> ```
> set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
> ```

this doesn't make sense to me: are you including custom `.cmake` snippets?

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

I believe it should be `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS` (note the `S`).

> ```
> set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
> ```

this should also not be required, unless you have headers in the root of your ROS package.

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2019-06-04**:
Oops! :) Corrected! sorry about that!